# Need to create a dynamic matrix from two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, matrix

I have two MySQL tables which have following schemas.

Students:

```
+------------+--------------+
| student_id | student_name |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | John Doe     |
+------------+--------------+
| 2          | Robert Brown |
+------------+--------------+
| 3          | Charlie Cox  |
+------------+--------------+
```

Subjects:

```
+------------+--------------+
| student_id | subject_name |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | History      |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | Biology      |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | Mathematics  |
+------------+--------------+
| 2          | Literature   |
+------------+--------------+
| 2          | Physics      |
+------------+--------------+
| 2          | Mathematics  |
+------------+--------------+
| 3          | Literature   |
+------------+--------------+
| 3          | Geography    |
+------------+--------------+
```

Now I want a result matrix something like below:-

```
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| student_name | Biology | Geography | History | Literature | Mathematics | Physics |
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| John Doe     | Y       | N         | Y       | N          | Y           | N       |
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| Robert Brown | N       | N         | N       | Y          | Y           | Y       |
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| Charlie Cox  | N       | Y         | N       | Y          | N           | N       |
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

The columns having subjects may grow more as more subjects are added to database. Based on my requirements there have been suggestions of pivot but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: You need a dynamic pivot if you don't know the subjects upfront.

Comment: 'suggestions of pivot but I am not familiar with that' - search for mysql pivot